# Periods of Fibonacci numbers in mod. Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Work out the periods $π(n)$ of the $\mod n$ such that

$$f_k ≡ f_{k+π(n)} \mod n$$

I got $π(2)=3$,$π(3)=8$,$π(4)=6$ by computing it and looking at the periods.

**Now Part 2**

Prove that for all integers $n > 1$ there exists a period $π(n)$. I need to consider the modulo of consecutive terms and find it that way.
That is $f_k \mod n$ and $f_{k+1} \mod n$

I was thinking of simply saying that it's periodic, thus every mod must repeat.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it asks why the Fibonacci sequence modulo $n$ is periodic for each $n$. (Being periodic being equivalent to existence of a period $\pi(n)$.) Claiming it is periodic because it is periodic does not sound like it should answer the question. Could you tell me where I'm misunderstanding your question?